# Easiest way to model hair like this?

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting, hair, sculpt

So I have my face mesh but Im not sure if I should extrude from the head or make a seperate mesh.

[image: Want it to look like this]

[image: face mesh]

Answer (score 1):

select a part of the head

[image]

-> double it in edit mode with Shift - D

move it up

[image]

mesh -> separate selection

[image]

rename the new object to "hair" and remodel it as you like

[image]

[image]

and yeah, i know i would win every modelling contest with my modelling art - it's marvellous ;) and the hair is looking so amazing (sorry, i couldn't resist - i cannot model at all)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134920/discussion-on-answer-by-chris-easiest-way-to-model-hair-like-this).